# SSRS barchart label position

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm going nuts trying to control the label position for a barchart. I want the labels to be above the bars and it *mostly* works. For a large dataset, a couple of bars have the label inside the bar and the rest are all above. For a smaller dataset, the labels all are above. I can't find ANY combination of properties that work consistently.[image: Bar chart pain]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the series in your chart then on the right side where the properties are under **Labels -> Position -> Change to Top**.